# Playing song in jPlayer that was uploaded via Paperclip - Ruby on Rails - jQuery - jPlayer

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, html5-audio, jplayer

Thanks for any help in advance.

So, I'm storing songs in a filesystem with Paperclip. I'm then trying to play these songs with jPlayer.

I have followed all the directions but can't seem to get the audio playing via clicking on a link_to method that is supposed to parse the audio to jPlayer.

Basically a song should play when the button 'Play Song' is clicked.

My jPlayer function looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: '<source>'
            });
        },
        swfPath: "jplayerflash",
        supplied: "mp3",
    });
  });
```

My view looks like this:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Play Song', song_upload.song.url, :class => "html5" %></td>
```

The audio files are stored via paperclip in assets/user_song_uploads...
The songs are all MP3 format and I'm using Chrome so everything should work.

The problem comes in when trying to set the media in jPlayer.

[Link to how jPlayer should be implemented](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/quick-start-guide/step-7-audio/)
[This where I initially learned how to implement a music listening application. Half way through in the section 'Streaming with HTML5 Audio' is why i used '' - but clearly not working with this implementation.](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-simple-music-streaming-app-with-ruby-on-rails/)

Comment: Not familiar with jPlayer, but what is `mp3: '<source>'` supposed to do? IMO, clicking on the link generated in your call to `link_to` should just plain open the mp3. I can't see the connection between the jPlayer and the link? Could you point us to the docs you found this in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the late response but I figured out my answer.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    swfPath: "/app/assets/jplayerflash",
    supplied: "mp3",
    wmode: "window"
});
$('a.play').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1")
        .jPlayer("setMedia", {mp3: this.href })
        .jPlayer("play");
```

and my view:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Play Song', song_upload.song.url, :class => "play" %></td>
```

Comment: Thanks for this post! Is that `swfPath` correct? I had to drop off the `/app` part of the path.

Comment: For me it ism you can specify wherever you place jplayerflash.